# Inline Header With Background-Color & Padding

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to determine if there is a way to style inline headers that span multiple lines using a background color.

The issue I'm having is with the `padding` is broken on any lines that wrap.

Example

**CSS and HTML**

```css
h1 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
  background: purple;

  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel scelerisque neque.</h1>
```

[Here is the link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hMMxM/)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Here is an image of what im trying to achieve.
http://i.imgur.com/12uSGRy.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the `image` you posted this is the solution I came up with:

**CSS and HTML**

```css
.header-container{
  position: relative;
  background: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
  display: inline;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 60px;
}
h1:after{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff; /*your page bg color*/
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel scelerisque neque.</h1>
</div>
```

Here's the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hMMxM/9/)

Comment: block element will extend the background colour. 
I added an example image.

Comment: That is pretty cool, wouldn't have thought of that! This will work. 
Appreciate this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap it in a `container` with padding? And then remove padding and line height from the `h1`.

CSS and HTML

```css
div {
  padding:20px;
}
h1 {
  display: inline;
  background: purple;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vel scelerisque neque</h1>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hMMxM/5/

Comment: Its part of the design. The padding needs to be applied to the header.

Answer (score 0):

try

http://jsfiddle.net/hMMxM/10/

```
$("h1").each(function() 
    {
        var headerContent = $(this).text().split(' ');

        for (var i = 1; i < headerContent.length; i++) 
        {
            headerContent[i] = '<span class="subhead">' + headerContent[i] + '</span>';
        }

        $(this).html(headerContent.join(' '));
    }
);
```